# If $G$ is a paracompact topological group, then is $G \times G$ paracompact?

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups

If $G$ is a paracompact topological group, then is $G \times G$ paracompact?

This question is raised by [Gepner and Henriques](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701916) (first paragraph of 2.2). Of course, this is not true for arbitrary paracompact spaces, as shown by the [Sorgenfrey plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space#Examples).

Actually -- what's an example of a non-paracompact group?

Comment: An easy example: A product of uncountably many infinite discrete spaces is not paracompact. Therefore $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{R}$ is a non-paracompact group.

Comment: Avoid writing a question in the title without repeating it... this makes confusion, especially if you add a second question below. I edited accordingly.

Comment: @YCor Thanks, that's a good point about re-stating the question.

Comment: @JohannesHahn Thanks, I wish I had realized there were such easy examples!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am at a [topology conference](https://sites.google.com/site/summertopology2018/) today, and among the many good topologists here is Jan van Mill, a leading expert on topological groups. I ran your question by him, thinking he might know the answer off the top of his head. He did -- the answer is that if $G$ is a paracompact topological group, then $G \times G$ need not be paracompact.

The construction of such a group can be found in

> Yinhe Peng and Liuzhen Wu, "A Lindelöf group with non-normal square" ([link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321360206_A_LINDELOF_GROUP_WITH_NON-LINDELOF_SQUARE))

Their main theorem is that there is a Hausdorff group $G$ such that $G$ is Lindelöf but $G \times G$ is not. Every Hausdorff group is regular, every regular Lindelöf space is paracompact, and every Hausdorff paracompact space is normal. Thus their group $G$ is paracompact, while $G \times G$ is not.

More information on Peng and Wu's work can be found in [these slides](https://www.fields.utoronto.ca/programs/scientific/14-15/forcing/slides/wednesday/Peng.pdf) of Yinhe Peng's.

Comment: Thanks! I see— you explain why G is paracompact. On the other hand from the title I see that GxG is not normal. But it is Hausdorff and every paracompact Hausdorff space is normal. So GxG is not paracompact.

Comment: I just realized that Gepner and Henriques (my motivating context) are working in compactly-generated spaces, which might change the answer. Perhaps I will ask this as a separate question...